# What is this called and what does it do? (Part of a Generic Repository)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm reading up on generic repositories. I keep stumbling into bits of code that I don't understand. I don't know if there's a specific name for them or not.

This is the most complicated example I've seen:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetByQuery(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> query = null, 
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderby = null, 
    string includeProperties = "");
```

I know it (whatever it is) apparently returns an `IEnumerable`, but I have no idea how to read that mess of gobbledygook let alone how to go about using it.

Edit: I'm more interested in knowing what that's an example **of** than a breakdown of that specific example. I need to know what they're called before I can find something that explains the syntax. LINQ??

Edit 2: I'm asking a much, much simpler question than the one being answered. All I want to know is "what are a few **search terms** I can use in order to research the above code?"

Comment: i like that you used "gobbledygook" -- Expressions can look messy

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about which parts of the gook are gobbledy.  Do you know what generics are?  Do you know what a delegate is?  Are you confused about how `IQueryable<T>` works?  Do you not understand the `Expression<>` bit?  There's an excellent answer breaking down this particular method already, but maybe those terms will help guide your basic research.

Comment: I've heard of generics and delegates. I've never seen anything with with the terms IQueryable, Func, or Expression<> before. The only 'Expression' I've ever heard of referred to math (as in 2+2). I'm assuming though there is a specific context in which those things occur together. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 9):

Note, all of this is an extremely educated guess, based on how `IQueryable<T>` work.

Breaking it down into three parts:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> query = null
```

This is a where clause, it's the same signature that's passed to the `Where` extension method on `IQueryable<T>`.

You'd pass an expression, which is represented in code the same way that a lambda is; the C# compiler knows that the parameter is looking for an `Expression` and will compile it into an expression tree and not a delegate.

For example, assuming `T` is a `Person` class with an `int` property `Age`, you could filter out any `Person` returned by the `IQueryable<Person>` that is 30 years or older with the following:

```
p => p.Age > 30
```

---

```
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy
```

This is just a delegate which if provided, will allow you to set an order.  Assuming you want the `Person` instances ordered by age, you'd use:

```
q => q.OrderBy(p => p.Age)
```

This is because the return type is `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, which how extension methods such as `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` pop up only after you call `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`; those extension methods are only defined on `IOrderedQueryable<T>` (it's little more than a marker interface).

---

```
includeProperties
```

This gives away that it's using the Entity Framework underneath the covers.  When you call `Include` in the Entity Framework, it allows you to get related entities (via foreign key) and load the entities related to the entity being returned in the query.

Let's say the `Person` class has a property `Father` of type `Person`.  If you wanted to query `Person` instances and have the `Father` property returned as well, then you'd call `Include("Father")` to indicate that not only should Entity Framework get the instances of `Person`, but it should resolve the `Father` relationship as well.

---

`IEnumerable<T>` return type

This is returned so that you don't have access to the `IQueryable<T>` instance and forces you to materialize the result set (as you iterate through it).

An implementation that does this *should* be returning the a materialized list (`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`), or something that is not just (assumedly) a cast of `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

It's also an indication of the trust that the writer of the method has for the clients; as `IQueryable<T>` isn't returned, it indicates that it doesn't trust clients to not make inefficient database calls (which is a valid concern).

Comment: I should note that it's my opinion that the method in question is definitely a hinderance; it's really making using Entity Framework that much harder.

What you should ideally do is have access to an `IQueryable<T>` (with some setup of basic filters/ordering) and let the caller materialize the list themselves, optionally attaching some additional query logic/operations before doing so.

Comment: I don't know what that is either, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user2146821 if you don't understand this answer, which is quite clear and a good breakdown, you've got some basic research to do.

Comment: WHAT am I supposed to be researching? I don't what I posted an example OF. It's hard to look something up if you don't know what to call it. It's not mentioned in a single one of my C# books.

Comment: lambda expressions, for example.